# How to get the path for a given page?

Tags: octobercms

Suppose that in page A you want to put in a link to page B. How to make it declarative, so that, even if the path for page B changes, the link code in page A's template can stay the same? I'm looking for something like:

```
{{ page_path("where/pageB/is/pageB.htm") }}
```

And it would output: `http://localhost/this-is-the-path-for-pageB`.

Comment: Try `{{ 'page-name'|page }}`, where *page-name* is a name of your page in the cms section.

Comment: https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/filter-page

Comment: @qwaz that's what I needed, feel free to submit it as an answer.